# Selenium firefox driver fails on ubuntu

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using java web driver for firefox 23.0 to run selenium tests. At a certain point, the test fails and the browser exits saying "waiting for evaluate.js failed" (see full Java console log). Any solutions please?

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed
Command duration or timeout: 10.66 seconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-51-generic-pae', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Session ID: 3d330756-afeb-4aca-a770-89d9ef1349da
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=23.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at org.openlmis.UiUtils.TestWebDriver.handleScrollByPixels(TestWebDriver.java:120)
    at org.openlmis.pageobjects.RolesPage.createRoleWithSuccessMessageExpected(RolesPage.java:235)
    at org.openlmis.functional.E2EUpload.uploadCSVFiles(E2EUpload.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4ecaf82108b2a6cc6f006aae81961236eba93358', time: '2013-05-22 12:00:17'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.2.0-51-generic-pae', java.version: '1.7.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.r(file:///tmp/anonymous5836509103412085087webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8360)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.runWhenTrue/g(file:///tmp/anonymous5836509103412085087webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:392)
    at <anonymous class>.fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify(file:///tmp/anonymous5836509103412085087webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:386)

===============================================
Custom suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: There is an issue in Selenium bug tracking system for this problem: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6051

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ran into this problem as well.  Upgrading from Selenium 2.32 to 2.35 seemed to solve this problem for us.